# Is it possible to see the @namespace header value of (other) installed userscripts?

Tags: javascript, browser, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I know it is possible for a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey userscript to access it's own header data from `GM_info`.

But is it possible for a userscript (or any other code) to get this information for another installed userscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
A userscript can only see its own information.  And due to both security concerns and lack of perceived need, that is unlikely to change.

In theory, you could write a full browser extension/plugin that could read the Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey config files and extract that information, but that would be way more effort than it's worth.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So it **is** possible, just hard to do?

Comment: Not possible at all for a userscript.  Yes, very hard to do but, in fairness, I haven't helped code a plugin in years and I wouldn't be surprised if it's no longer possible with that approach either.  Browsers have gotten much better with that kind of security.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry not enough reputation to upvote.